# Fragment reload on popBackStack

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel

I have an issue with the data observation and the fragment backstack on a single activity application.
For example, I have parent fragment A which will observe data from viewmodel and fill to ExitText. User can change the information in the EditText. Fragment A can navigate to fragment B and listen to B result by using setFragmentResultListener.
The problem is, when popBackStack from B, the changed data on fragment B will be revert to data from viewmodel because I observed the data in onCreateView.
Is there anyway I can retain the changed data from fragment A after popBackStack from fragment B?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SharedViewModel** since both fragments share same activity. In this way view model does not die and you can use the data.

Offical doc:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing